# ASP.NET Web Forms and JavaScript Module Pattern Design

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, webforms, javascript

I need to design how to implement JavaScript module pattern in existing large .NET Web Forms application. Currently there are no rules and lot of JavaScript code uses global variables. The problem is also with communication between server and JavaScript client code, currently lot of JavaScript functions are called from code-behind classes and are inlined into page.

**Current JavaScript usage example**

A server control adds link to some JavaScript file to the `<head>` element so it will be downloaded. The file contains one or more global functions. Then the server control call's this global functions whenever it needs them, like following:

```
string script = string.Format("GlobalFunction1('{0}');", param);
```

And this string is inserted somewhere inside the `<body>` element in the HTML. There are no rules and the server can call any of the global function whenever it needs them.

**The main goals for improvements are:**

- Separate server-side code from client-side JavaScript. This means no chaotic inline calls for JavaScript global functions.
- JavaScript self functioning modules, which are not dependent on each other.
- JS modules should not expose anything to global scope.
- Every JS module has only one place to initialize itself.
- Server-side should be able to populate some parameters to JS module initialization.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the approach that I came with:*

### How would it look like on Server-Side

- Every Control has its own JavaScript module
- Every Control is wrapped inside its root `<div>` element.
- Server can call this helper method in every page life-cycle: `ScriptModule.AddParam("param_name", "param_value");` This params will be added to the Control's wrapper (div) on `pre_render` event call as HTML5's `data-` attributes.
- Finally Server registers the module with `ScriptModule.Register("module_name", "path_to_js_file", "controlWrapperId")`.

**This results in these steps in HTML:**

- The `<script>` file (`path_to_js_file`) is inserted into the page which links to desired module's file.
- The parameters are added into Control's wrapper (div) through `data-` attributes.
- At the end of the page the inlined `Core.start("module_name", "controlWrapperId");` is inserted, which starts the module's initialization. This method is discussed later in client-side section.

### How would it look like on Client-Side

The first file that is downloaded is the *Core.js* file, which registers one global variable *Core* that is used to define new modules.

Every JavaScript file will be defined as module. This module should not expose anything to the global scope and should be self functioning. The template follows:

```
// 1. first param is module's name
// 2. than the array with dependencies to helpers modules
// 3. than the callback with following parameters
//    a. jQuery object which references wrapper (i.e. div) of this module
//    b. params hash-object, which contains server parameters from wrapper's -data attributes in format
//       {  'param1_name': 'param_val',
//          'param2_name': 'param2_val'  }
//    c. then the external dependencies to helper modules
Core.htmlModule('mod name', ['external', 'deps'], function ($w, params, external, deps) {
    // Here the module initializes itself
    // it can communicate with other modules through Core.publish(); Core.subscribe();
    // it does not return anything, because it is HTML module and so it does not expose anything
});
```

The second parameter defines so-called helper modules, which are for code reusing. Due to the *normal* module's independence and inability to expose some functions outside, there is needed something to share same code. This can be achieved by defining helper module, which can expose some of its properties and then be referenced from normal module.